# endless directory list php

Tags: php, alphabetical, directory-listing

i have this php code to list all files in a directory and output filesize and a download link.

```
<?
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
$size = array(' B',' kB',' MB',' GB',' TB',' PB',' EB',' ZB',' YB');
$factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$size[$factor];
}

$excludedFiles = array('.','..');

$excludedExtensions = array ('html','htm','php');

// Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] = strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] = strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);


// Define the full path to your folder from root
$dir = "./";

// Open the folder
$dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $dir");

// Loop through the files
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

$extn = explode('.',$file);
$extn = array_pop($extn);

if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) && !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)){

if($file == "." || $file == ".." )


continue;

echo "<tr>
      <td>
     <a class='Testo' href=\"$file\" download>$file</a></td>
     <td><font class='TestoPiccoloBo'>[" . human_filesize(filesize($file)) . "]</font></td>
    </tr>";
 }
 }

// Close
closedir($dir_handle);



?>
```

i wanted the list to be alphabetically ordered so i added

```
$files = scandir($dir);
```

after the `$dir` line and

```
foreach ($files as $file){
```

after the `while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {` line

and a

```
}
```

before the `closedir($dir_handle);` line

now the files list in alphabetical order, but the list is endless. the list starts over and over, like a loop.
What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to accomplish this?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your folder in an array and sort it with the php sort function. Then print them :

```
<?
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
$size = array(' B',' kB',' MB',' GB',' TB',' PB',' EB',' ZB',' YB');
$factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$size[$factor];
}

$excludedFiles = array('.','..');
$arrayFiles = array();
$excludedExtensions = array ('html','htm','php');

// Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] = strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] = strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);


// Define the full path to your folder from root
$dir = "./";

// Open the folder
$dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $dir");

// Loop through the files
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

$extn = explode('.',$file);
$extn = array_pop($extn);

if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) && !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)){

if($file == "." || $file == ".." )
continue;

$arrayFiles[] =  $file;

 }
 } // dunno what are these } so i put my loop after

// Close
closedir($dir_handle);

sort($arrayFiles);

foreach ($arrayFiles as $file) {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>
     <a class='Testo' href=\"$file\" download>$file</a></td>
     <td><font class='TestoPiccoloBo'>[" . human_filesize(filesize($file)) . "]</font></td>
    </tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! I just added `$` before  `arrayFiles[] =  $file;`

Comment: Great! And thank you for the return on my typo problem :) It's edited.